# How can Spring Boot Admin send custom notifications for actuator metric change?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Spring Boot Admin provides notification feature only for status up or down of the application. I want to send email notification for some metric change in actuator endpoint. could you please guide me how can I configure this?

Simple notification for UP/DOWN of the application

```
@Configuration
public class NotifierConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Notifier notifier;

    @Primary
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public RemindingNotifier remindingNotifier() {
        RemindingNotifier notifier = new RemindingNotifier(notifier,          repository);
        notifier.setReminderPeriod(Duration.ofMinutes(10)); 
        notifier.setCheckReminderInverval(Duration.ofSeconds(10)); 
        return notifier;
    }
}
```

This is for the UP?DOWN of the application. I want to configure in some metric of the actuator endpoint

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an easy way to do that at the moment.

Notifications are sent by classes implementing the [Notifier](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/notify/Notifier.java) interface. These classes are consuming a *Flux* of [InstanceEvent](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/domain/events/InstanceEvent.java) to produce these notifications. These events are triggered when there are changes on an instance info/status actuator endpoint, when an instance is registered/unregistered, etc. To create notifications for actuator metrics, you should therefore create a custom [InstanceEvent](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/domain/events/InstanceEvent.java) (say *InstanceMetricsChangedEvent*) each time there's some changes on an instance metrics actuator endpoint. Maybe you can have a look at how [InstanceInfoChangedEvent](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/domain/events/InstanceInfoChangedEvent.java) are triggered and see if it's possible to do something similar with your *InstanceMetricsChangedEvent*. Have a look at : [InfoUpdater](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/services/InfoUpdater.java) and [InfoUpdateTrigger](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/services/InfoUpdateTrigger.java).